# iOS - KeychainItemWrapper assertion failure when setting email

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychainitemwrapper

I am using the KeychainItemWrapper to store my logged in users email and password.
With the following code:

```
                    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"loginData" accessGroup:nil];
                [keychainItem setObject:@"myString" forKey: (id)kSecAttrService];
                [keychainItem setObject:email forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
                [keychainItem setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

I get the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain],
```

If I change this line:

```
[keychainItem setObject:email forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

To this:

```
[keychainItem setObject:@"whatever" forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

It works. So it seems that I can't set an email to the Keychain. What should I do?

Comment: What type is `email`? When looking at the documentation, it should be a string. Based on this line of comment: [KeychainItemWrapper](https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641#file-keychainitemwrapper-m-L70)

Comment: (NSString *)email it's a string indeed!

Comment: The weird thing is, the documentation doesn't throw the error you're seeing. Could you link to the Github repo you're using KeychainItemWrapper from? Or is that a native class?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641 I'm using this one. Should I use another one?

Comment: Try changing `forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount` to `forKey:(__bridge id):kSecAttrAccount`, that might work.
If it doesn't, set a breakpoint at that line (`keychainItem setObject:email...`) and please show what the debug console tells you.

Comment: It doesn't work sadly. It only shows the error I put above... ```*** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], ``` What is the way to go?